# How to successfully use an existing workspace in multiple versions of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am working on a large project where there are mutiple eclipse-based IDEs that are used for different (but overlapping) tasks.  For example, we use an eclipse-based IDE to develop business rules, and a different eclipse-based IDE for version control.  The versions of eclipse may vary from one IDE to another, and the loaded plug-ins may also.

Based on painful experience, I'm pretty sure that directly using the same workspace from multiple versions of eclipse is a bad idea, because the metadata may be vastly different/incompatible.

Is the best way to "reuse" a workspace to create a new workspace, and then import the old workspace's projects to the new workspace?  If so, that implies that any updates to one need to be duplicated for the other.  Is there another, better way?

Comment: I agree with your finding of sharing workspaces between different Eclipse versions.  I can recommend using maven projects and then use m2eclipse to allow Eclipse to work with them.

Comment: I do this all the time without a problem. Eclipse's metadata files are backwards and forwards compatible. I develop plugins that are compatible with multiple versions and I test using multiple versions, using the same test workspaces. Never have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this scenario just recently and my solution was to use git to version the .metadata directory, then create a branch, switch to the correct branch before starting eclipse.

To automate the process I created a shell script to check for any changes in the current branch, commit if needed then switch to the correct branch and start eclipse - working with Juno and Mars.